# Can't find controller method in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I go to my page `/step/3` I got this message

```
Unknown action

The action 'step3' could not be found for UsersController
```

My `routes.rb`:

```
get '/step/3', :to => 'users#step3'
```

This method define in controller Users

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def step3
        ...
    end
end
```

Early it's work fine, but I can't understend why it stop work correctly

P.S. Other controllers works fine

Comment: Please show all `UsersController` code.

Comment: I remove all methods and for this moment in my controller I have only one method `step3`

Comment: When did it stop working correctly?

Comment: It's can't find method which define in my controller

Comment: I don't understand. I ask you after what your action it stopped working properly? If I understood your question correctly, it used to work.

Comment: I didn't know, It was thousand lines of code ago. I just see this crash in registration...Sorry, but if I know what I do wrong early, I try fix it by myself :)

Comment: can you post the error log in details?

Comment: is your action name `step` or `step3` ??

Comment: what version of Rails are you using? Was there a rails upgrade between it working and not working? (And, do you now have a failing test so you'll know when it's fixed, and when it stops working again in the future?) I also wonder how that route appears in 'rake routes' output, and whether another line in the route file was added that matches it first now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try defining your route.rb as `match '/step/3', :to => 'users#step3'`